How to anchor the bottom drawer to the bottom of the screen?
Below is my code to make a View in SwiftUI. I want to attach my bottom drawer to the bottom of the screen.
struct BottomDrowerView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 100
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack{
                
            }
        }
            .background(Color.red)
            .offset(y: offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged{ value in
                        let startLocation = value.startLocation
                        offset = startLocation.y + value.translation.height
                    }
            )
        }
    }


I tried,
 .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
but it didn't work.
